# rdrop2 error using drop_create()

Tags: r, dropbox, mkdir

I get the following error when trying to create a directory in my Dropbox using rdrop2 in R.

> drop_create(dirname)
>
> Error in drop_list_folder(path, recursive, include_media_info, include_deleted,  : 
>     Conflict (HTTP 409).

The folder creation works fine in a local copy of my working folders.
Do you know how to fix it?

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you print out the body of the HTTP response? It should contain a more useful error message.